# Cannot convert return expression of type 'FetchedResults<>' to return type '[String]'

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to search through a list of bookmarks by name stored in Core Data but I'm getting this error next to 'return items' in var searchResults

"Cannot convert return expression of type 'FetchedResults <MyBookmark to return type '[String]'"

```
 @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyBookmark.name, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
 private var items: FetchedResults<MyBookmark>
 @State private var searchText = ""

         ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self) { myBookmark in                        
                    Text(myBookmark.name!)
                    Text(myBookmark.url!)
                   }
                   .searchable(text: $searchText)




         var searchResults: [String] {
            if searchText.isEmpty {
               return items
          } else {
              return items.filter { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
            }
         }
```

MyBookmark

```
@objc(MyBookmark)
public class MyBookmark: NSManagedObject, BaseModel {
    static var all: NSFetchRequest<MyBookmark> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<MyBookmark> = MyBookmark.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        return request
    }
    
}


extension MyBookmark {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MyBookmark> {
        return NSFetchRequest<MyBookmark>(entityName: "MyBookmark")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var url: String?

}

extension MyBookmark : Identifiable {

}
```

This is for a macOS app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute your fetch request again when the search filter changes. To do that you need to set the predicate of the fetch request.

Add a new property to handle this

```
var query: Binding<String> {
    Binding {
        searchText
    } set: { newValue in
        searchText = newValue
        if newValue.isEmpty {
            items.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        } else {
            items.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", newValue)            }
    }
}
```

And then use the `.searchable` modifier together with this property

```
var body: some View {
    ForEach {
        //...
    }
    .searchable(text: query)
}
```

Comment: I get 'Cannot convert return expression of type 'FetchedResults<MyBookmark>' to return type '[MyBookmark]' on 'return items' for if searchText.isEmpty

Comment: @swiftnoob yes my mistake, since this is a fetch request you can't filter the result directly but instead you need to set a predicate for your fetch request. I will update the answer

Answer (score 2):

That var must return an array of `String`, but you are returning the array `items`, which is an array of type `MyBookmark`.

Solution: convert the array to a type of `[String]`.

Replace that variable with:

```
         var searchResults: [String] {
            if searchText.isEmpty {
               return items.compactMap { $0.name }
          } else {
              return items.compactMap { $0.name }.filter { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
            }
         }
```